# Is there any stochastic order between a r.v. $A$ and $\min(A,B)$ where $B$ is another r.v.?

Tags: probability

I was wondering if there is any stochastic order between a r.v. $A$ and $\min(A,B)$ where $B$ is any other r.v..

Surely, $A$ first order stochastically dominates $\min(A,B)$ as $F_A(x)\leq F_{\min(A,B)}(x)$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Would there be any other ordering between the two, such as likelihood ratio order, etc.?